# Python и работа с другими устройствами и комьютерами с помощью PYRO

Tags: python

Кто-нибудь работа с помощью библиотеки PYRO в Python с удалёнными объектами или например, с уладённым компьютером на Linux, или с контроллером каким-то, на котором работает Linux. Необходимо осуществить соединение и передачу данных. Где можно посмотреть какие-то примеры по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, собственно, Гугл отвечает вполне конкретно:
[Simple Example,](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html#simple-example)
[Different machines.](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/tutorials.html#running-it-on-different-machines)